# WinDbg - How to filter threads by stack trace or exception text?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, dump, sos

I have a huge dump. There are about 1000 threads captured within it. I want to know which threads are calling 'MethindA', which threads are processing exception with text 'someText'. How to do it?

**Details**

I use `!threads` cmd (from sos), which prints lines like this:

```
  32  262 3f50 000000f2b3d90190  3029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000f090ec3840 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) System.Net.WebException 000000eca7efb008 (nested exceptions)
```

printing exception info from this line prints something like this:

```
Host : xxx.com.
Response:<html><body><b>Http/1.1 Service Unavailable</b></body> </html>
Version:1.1.1.0
InnerException:   System.Net.WebException, Use !PrintException 000000edb4208d60 to see more.
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000EC386194A0 00007FF96C775607 UNKNOWN!MyLibAccess.Services.MyLibService+<ExecuteAsync>d__145`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()+0x6f7
    000000EC38616E70 00007FF9C966E814 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0xd34d54
    000000EC38616EB0 00007FF9C8939A0D mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x3d
```

I want to do something like this:

```
!threads where stacktrace contains 'MyLibAccess'
!threads where callstack contains 'Int.Parse()'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use the pde debugger extension from Andrew Richards. It has a grep command that filters the output of a windbg command.

Answer (score 2):

Download [MEX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53304) and look at the help for the `!us`/`!uniquestacks` command. It is extremely powerful and will easily handle what you want to do. I should add that this may not be as clean with managed code. If `!mex.us` isn't as clean as you'd like, then run `!mex.grep` on the output of `!sosex.mk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!dumpstack` and `!clrstack` commands to get the managed stacks.

To run those commands on all threads, use `~*e <command>`.

Now you need a way to deal with the all the output. The built-in way would be to pass it to the shell and invoke the `findstr` command like this, (where `!!` is a shortcut for `.shell`):

```
0:000> !! -ci "~*e !clrstack" findstr "Console.ReadLine()"
0030f124 714e50f0 System.Console.ReadLine() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\console.cs @ 1984]
.shell: Process exited
```

Probably faster and without the risk of invoking strange shell commands: use the `!grep` command of the [PDE Extension (OneDrive)](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957%217152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957) as suggested by [Lieven Keersmakers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers) already:

```
0:000> !grep Console.ReadLine() ~*e !clrstack
0030f124 714e50f0 System.Console.ReadLine() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\console.cs @ 1984]
```

Unfortunately, both ways will not tell you, in which thread the exception occured, because the output of that line will be removed. Therefore, lets change the order of commands a bit.

1. Cycle through all threads
2. Print the thread ID
3. Check if the thread contains the expected piece of stack

Example:

```
0:000> ~*e .printf "0x%x\n", @@c++(@$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread);!grep Console.ReadLine() !clrstack
0x1ad4
0030f124 714e50f0 System.Console.ReadLine() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\console.cs @ 1984]
0x17c0
0x600
0x1cf8
0x54c
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to filter threads by stack trace or exception text:

```
.shell -ci "!threads" find "MyLibAccess"
```